# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Security?

Tags: 14.04, security

[Ubuntu 14.04 on 2014 Retina MacBook Pro 15" using rEFInd]

(*ThomasW's [Why is everybody so concerned about etc/passwd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654923/why-is-everybody-so-concerned-about-etc-passwd) link addresses my initial comments about accessibility to `passwd` and other files, so I've removed my comments here.*)  Though I still believe in the principle of denying information to the potential attackers.

Whilst trying to fix a Unity GUI issue which has rendered my account unusable, I've found what I believe is a much bigger issue!

I booted into 'Single User Mode' thinking that I would be able to log into a TTY terminal and fix things through it.  But the boot process paused at:

```
usbhid 1-8.1:1.0: can't add hid device: -71
usbhid 1-8.2:1.0: can't add hid device: -71
```

So I switched to TTY (Ctrl-Alt-F7) and since it was showing a cursor, I pressed `Enter`.  I now found myself with the root user prompt in root's home directory.  **I wasn't asked for a password!**
I created a new user, added them to the *sudo* group, and:
- *when* I used the *exit* command, a few more boot steps were performed (last of which was `* Restoring resolver state...` and it stopped.  So I returned to TTY F1 and now had a login prompt.  (I tried to login as root with no password and, as would be expected, I failed.  *The root account is disabled as per default*)
- *when* I used the *reboot* command, the boot up sequence continued until the login splash screen, and then a reboot was triggered.

(I thought you could only do this sort of thing by using a Live USB and chrooting to the fixed drive.)

This has been convenient for the current problem I'm trying to fix, but I don't think this is desirable in any other circumstance.

I've repeated these steps a few times whilst writing this post, so it's definitely repeatable.

Comment: @ThomasW. Agree that it was similar to the post you brought to my attention.  But I've now updated the post with a new problem.

Answer (score 4):

**Physical access** means you have all the power you need to do *anything*.  There is no need for an operating system to prevent anything when someone is actually touching the machine.

> This has been convenient for the current problem I'm trying to fix,

As intended.

> but I don't think this is desirable in any other circumstance.

I do not see an explanation why you believe this. Ubuntu, nor any other operating system, should ever hinder someone that can touch a machine.

Simple method: if you put in a Live DVD and boot from it, you can format the whole system without ever having to need to input a password. As it should be.

Even the most "secure" passwords you could set (the BIOS password asked during boot and before any device is accessed) can be circumvented: all motherboards have known default passwords that grant access to the system or using a simple screwdriver, the CMOS battery can be removed or the NVRAM chip can be swapped out.

Comment: My Mac does not have a disk player.

Comment: @gone: it doesn't even have screws... (re-read edited answer)

Comment: @gone same applies for booting from an USB stick, or an ISO from grub or an external DVD drive.

Comment: I understand what you're saying.  But Debian, and other distro's have gone to the trouble of disabling the root account, and the use case above shows there is a way of accessing it without any additional means.  Like you don't have to worry about someone seeing your plug in a CD or USB.

Comment: @gone [It's still there in Debian](http://serverfault.com/questions/482079/debian-boot-to-single-user-mode), just not so easy to access. Your machine is no more secure without it. The root account is disabled in Ubuntu as well.